# Not able to store four decimal values in custom_price & price columns in Quote_item table

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am trying to save four digit value after decimal (0.5312) to custom_price and price columns in quote item table but it is saving only two digits after decimal (0.53)

Comment: are you trying to insert directly in table or through code ?

Comment: Trough code like below,

$custom_price = 0.5312;
$item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
$item->setPrice($custom_price); 
$item->setBasePrice($custom_price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);

If i directly change in database then values are saving

Comment: by default magento is saving upto two decimal point like 0.53 only. You need to extend core function of custom price.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @BornCoder can you tell me in which file i need to change core function of custom price..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override core function `Mage_Core_Model_Store->roundPrice($price)` in a custom module.

**Change:**

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 2);
}
```

**To:**

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
```

Now values will save upto four decimal point.

Comment: Thank you , It is working.But roundPrice method is calling  so many times for different actions.How can i change that method only when saving customprice and price values to quote item,any ideas?

Comment: check , if you are getting any unique field or any information in custom price function, so you can add an `if` condition in `custom price function`.

Comment: There is no unique parameter as we can write if condition in roudPrice method.For original_price column in quote_ietm exact value is saving (even roundPrice is 2 ).Any ideas how it is working so that i can implement similar logic to custom_price also..

Comment: for quote item we have one more function to round price, let me check. I will update you.

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: Check 3rd point, i hope this will value you: https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-change-price-precision

Comment: It's not working dude...

Answer (score -1):

I think custom price is saving properly in database.
Please review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980164/magento-how-do-i-set-the-product-price-to-4-decimal-places).

Comment: changing core file is not a good practise , your answer showing to change core file which is not correct way. please avoid changing core files

Comment: make sure your not modifying app/code/core/ but make a copy of the dir/file to app/code/local/ instead.